# Retrieving the MS Graph API access token from a Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, session-storage

I want to retrieve an access token for the Microsoft Graph API from within a script running on a Sharepoint page. [This blog post](https://piasys.com/blog/getting-an-access-token-for-a-service-in-spfx/) describes what I want to do:

> Now, imagine that you want to directly read the value of the Access Token, because you want to use it manually in a low-level REST request [...] using any other HTTP low level request like AJAX, jQuery, etc.

The post then says

> Of course, in order to access the Access Tokens, you can directly access the Session Storage variables by key.

When I inspect the sessionStorage for a Sharepoint page, I see that the MS Graph API token is stored under a different domain associated with `https://webshell.suite.office.com` and the associated Iframe. It would seem that this token is therefore inaccessible from a script running under the `whatever.sharepoint.com` domain.

Does this mean that I need to create an SPFx app to access this token?